# No package information is being reported to landscape

Tags: apt, package-management, landscape

Hi I have recently added some new machines to our infrastructure.

I was able to register the computers with the UI, I can see CPU information, process etc.

However I still see:

```
2 computers have not reported package information
```

No packages.

I have followed and check information found on the page: https://help.landscape.canonical.com/FAQ#No_packages

> There can be several situations where the server will report no
>   installed or available packages for a Landscape client:
>
> bug: please make sure you are running the latest version of the
>   landscape-client package. Run a apt-get update && apt-get install
>   landscape-client session. the client machine was recently added to
>   Landscape: it can take up to 1h30min for a new Landscape client
>   machine to start uploading package information the client machine has
>   no access to Ubuntu package repositories for some reason, cron is
>   disabled on the client machine. Please make sure it's working properly
>   If you still have problems with packages not showing up in the web
>   interface, please use the Feedback option to report it to us.

The machines affected

1. running landscape-client version:15.06+bzr823-0ubuntu0~ubuntu14.04.1
2. Can access the Ubuntu repositories
3. Do have cron running.
4. Have been up and running for a few days.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot the issue further?

Comment: Resolved this, all the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d needed to have read permissions given to group and all.